# What might cause "Undefined Behaviour" in this parallel GPU code?

Tags: cuda, undefined-behavior

Lets assume core1 and core2 try writing their variables a and b to same memory location.

How can UB be explained here?

- We dont know if a or b is written to that memory location(as a last action).
- We dont even know what is written there (a garbage)
- Even the target memory address can be miscalculated(segfault?).
- Some logical gates make wrong currents and CPU disables itself
- CPU's frequency information becomes corrupt and goes high overclock(and break itself)

Can I assume only the first option is valid for all vendors of CPU( and GPU)?

I just converted below code into a parallel GPU code and it seems to be working fine.

Generic code:

```
for (j=0; j<YRES/CELL; j++) // this is parallelized
        for (i=0; i<XRES/CELL; i++) // this is parallelized
        {
            r = fire_r[j][i];
            g = fire_g[j][i];
            b = fire_b[j][i];
            if (r || g || b)
                for (y=-CELL; y<2*CELL; y++)
                    for (x=-CELL; x<2*CELL; x++)
                        addpixel(i*CELL+x, j*CELL+y, r, g, b, fire_alpha[y+CELL][x+CELL]);
   //addpixel accesses neighbour cells' informations and writes on them
   //and makes UB
            r *= 8;
            g *= 8;
            b *= 8;
            for (y=-1; y<2; y++)
                for (x=-1; x<2; x++)
                    if ((x || y) && i+x>=0 && j+y>=0 && i+x<XRES/CELL && j+y<YRES/CELL)
                    {
                        r += fire_r[j+y][i+x];
                        g += fire_g[j+y][i+x];
                        b += fire_b[j+y][i+x];
                    }
            r /= 16;
            g /= 16;
            b /= 16;
            fire_r[j][i] = r>4 ? r-4 : 0; // UB
            fire_g[j][i] = g>4 ? g-4 : 0; // UB
            fire_b[j][i] = b>4 ? b-4 : 0;
        }
```

Opencl:

```
"   int i=get_global_id(0); int j=get_global_id(1);"
"   int VIDXRES="+std::to_string(kkVIDXRES)+";"
                        "   int VIDYRES="+std::to_string(kkVIDYRES)+";"
                        "   int XRES="+std::to_string(kkXRES)+";"
                        "   int CELL="+std::to_string(kkCELL)+";"
                        "   int YRES="+std::to_string(kkYRES)+";"

                        "   int x=0,y=0,r=0,g=0,b=0,nx=0,ny=0;"

                        "       r = fire_r[j*(XRES/CELL)+i];"
                        "       g = fire_g[j*(XRES/CELL)+i];"
                        "       b = fire_b[j*(XRES/CELL)+i];"

                        "       int counterx=0;"
                        "       if (r || g || b)"
                        "       for (y=-CELL; y<2*CELL; y++){"
                        "       for (x=-CELL; x<2*CELL; x++){"
                        "       addpixel(i*CELL+x, j*CELL+y, r, g, b, fire_alpha[(y+CELL)*(3*CELL)+(x+CELL)],vid,vido);"
                        "       }}"

                        "       r *= 8;"
                        "       g *= 8;"
                        "       b *= 8;"
                        "       for (y=-1; y<2; y++){"
                        "       for (x=-1; x<2; x++){"
                        "       if ((x || y) && i+x>=0 && j+y>=0 && i+x<XRES/CELL && j+y<YRES/CELL)"
                        "       {"
                        "           r += fire_r[(j+y)*(XRES/CELL)+(i+x)];"
                        "           g += fire_g[(j+y)*(XRES/CELL)+(i+x)];"
                        "           b += fire_b[(j+y)*(XRES/CELL)+(i+x)];"
                        "       }}}"
                        "       r /= 16;"
                        "       g /= 16;"
                        "       b /= 16;"
                        "       fire_r[j*(XRES/CELL)+i] = (r>4 ? r-4 : 0);"
                        "       fire_g[j*(XRES/CELL)+i] = (g>4 ? g-4 : 0);"
                        "       fire_b[j*(XRES/CELL)+i] = (b>4 ? b-4 : 0);"
```

Here is picture of some rare artifacts of a 2D NDrangeKernel 's local boundary UB. Can these kill my GPU?

[image]

Comment: When I see the title, I directly want to answer *`behaviors that are not defined`*. :P

Comment: What exactly is your question? How "undefined behaviour" is generally defined? Or is this specifically about some GPU code?

Comment: I need to learn how bad can it be. I assume first option but not sure.

Comment: By definition there is no definition for how bad it can be. It *probably* won't kill your cat, but nobody guarantees it, because the undefined behaviour is explicitly not considered as something you should do or something someone thought all the way through.

Comment: I uploaded a picture of a rare artifacting caused by UB between compute units (the cvertical/horizontal trails ). Can it kill my GPU while I am debugging?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: unless you're running things in a continuous loop, there's no reason to overheat the GPU. you're not even near to the load that mining puts on a gpu :)

Comment: You won't kill the GPU, no more than playing crysis: you are just doing legal operations, in a very random order.

Comment: Undefined behaviour = avoiding behaviour that would incur a performance penalty to define!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On xf86 and xf86_64 architectures it means *We dont know if a or b is written to that memory location(as a last action)*, because load/store operations of 32 (for both) or 64 bit (xf86_64 only) **memory aligned** datatypes are atomic.

On other architectures usually *We dont even know what is written there (a garbage)* is a valid answer - for sure on RISC architectures, I currently don't know on GPU's.

Note that The fact the code works doesn't imply that it is correct and in the 99% of the times it's the source of sentences like "there's a compiler bug, the code was working until the previous version" or "the code works on the development machine. The server selected for production is broken" :)

EDIT:

On NVidia GPUs we have weakly-ordered memory model. In the [description on the Cuda C Programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#memory-fence-functions) it's not explicitly stated that store operations are atomic. The write operations come from the same thread, so it does not mean that load/store operations are atomic.

Comment: "If I enable optimization it doesn't do anything anymore"

Answer (score 1):

For the code above, IMHO the first option is the only possible one. Basically, if you assume that you have enough threads/processors to execute all the loops in parallel, the inner nested loops (the `x` and `y` ones) will have undetermined values.

For example, if we consider only the

```
r += fire_r[j+y][i+x];
```

section, the value at `fire_r[j+y][i+x]` can be the original one just as well as the result of another instance of the same loop being finished in another thread.