# Is a "reset" of ncurses possible or even necessary?

Tags: c, linux, ncurses

I have a C program, that uses ncurses, behaving strangely - it runs fine on one disk system but on another it ran fine the first time but now crashes (in an ncurses routine) after the program was interrupted via Ctrl-C.

Is there a local file or state setting somewhere that would possibly account for this instability? Can that be reset?

(I am not able to reboot the system, which is shared). The system is Ubuntu Linux: 3.2.0-65-generic #98-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 11 20:27:07 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: You are describing [Undefined Behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21705865/what-exactly-is-undefined-behaviour).

Comment: @jongware don't be rediculous.

Comment: Why not kill the process (kill -9) ?

Comment: Kill what process? As it crashes it is dead anyway. I cannot restart it on this disk system now without a crash. Probably an issue with the disk system, but I want to check that.

Comment: No, don't invert stuff. Probably a problem with your code.

Comment: what is a disk system anyway?

Comment: The code has been run multiple times before and is running now, on a different disk system. Though of course it could be an error in my code that only comes to light in corner cases, I accept that.

Comment: 1000 Bites, one system is local hardware, another is SMB mounted

Comment: What do you mean by a crash?

Comment: acm538@research0:/shared/cssamba0/staffstore/acm538$ ./analysis testcase1_control.xml case1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: What is the program supposed to do (other than not crash) when you use CTRL-C? Is there any special handling for CTRL-C in your code? Do you have a SIGINT handler?

Comment: @ChrisStratton: What's ridiculous about it? It's very likely that the program is crashing because its behavior is undefined. That doesn't help much in diagnosing or fixing the problem, though.

Comment: There is not nearly enough information here to guess what might be causing the program to crash. I don't believe that ncurses stores any information in files, though it does read terminfo data.  You haven't shown us any of your program's source. You're just going to have to track down the problem. Try narrowing down your program to the smallest version that exhibits the problem. You could also try running it under a debugger, probably `gdb`.

Comment: I have run it under gdb, that's why I know it's ncurses related. I asked a very specific question above, incidentally.

Comment: Perhaps your program called some ncurses function with invalid arguments, or perhaps an unrelated problem in your code corrupted memory and caused ncurses to fail. Without seeing any of your code, we can't diagnose the problem. As far as I know, the answer to your specific question is no; I don't believe ncurses itself stores any information that could affect later executions of a program. BTW, if you want me to be notified about a content you need to include an @ character followed by my name.

Comment: @Keith: that is exactly what I suggested. "Undefined Behavior" indeed means that code *may* run without any problem. The fact that it now crashes inside ncurses *probably* means nothing.

Comment: You still haven't explained what you mean by "disk system"; I can think of several things it might mean.

Comment: ncurses is simply a library, it doesn't have its own state which outlasts the process, though it does interact with the state of the terminal which will, and yes, you can reset the terminal state.  "undefined behavior" has a very specific meaning which it is extremely premature to suggest as an explanation here. But there is clearly a problem with the program.  What function does the crash occur within?  What are the arguments passed to it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: If a C program crashes, it's probably because it has exhibited undefined behavior, which just means that the C standard says nothing about how it should behave. There are no C constructs (except perhaps a call to `abort`) whose defined behavior is a crash. It's quite easy for a C program's behavior to be undefined: accessing an array outside its bounds, dereferencing a null or uninitialized pointer, etc. etc.

Comment: You haven't told us how it crashes. Is there an error message?